# Documenting thrown RuntimeExceptions for Interfaces

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I have the following interface:

```
public interface DataReceiver {
    public Data getData();
}
```

The concrete Receivers have different sources for the data and therefore throw different exceptions:

```
public class DeviceDataReceiver implements DataReceiver {
    // Gets data from some hardware device
    // Exceptions include: DeviceNotConnected, DeviceNotLicensed, RequestTimeout, etc
    public Data getData() { ... }
}

public class FileDataReceiver implements DataReceiver {
    // Gets data from a file on disc
    // Exceptions include: FileNotFound, BadFormat
    public Data getData() { ... }
}
```

I documented these RuntimeExceptions in the according classes using the `@throws` Javadoc tag.

What i am struggling with is how to document the interface, since it will be the first thing a user of my library looks at, when he gets an error (I use the interface throughout my public API instead of the concrete classes). Documenting all the exceptions of the derived classes doesn't sound very appealing to me, since they have no relation at all.

Any best practices for this scenario?

Comment: Well should a client handle a `FileNotFound` differently than a `DeviceNotLicensed` exception? After all, if you have a generic interface, future implementations may throw different kinds of exceptions and the client can't generally know which kind of implementation it is using...

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception, so `FileDataReceiver` needs to currently wrap and rethrow it (and any other checked exception) as a `RuntimeException`, right?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes it does that atm.

Comment: Perhaps then you could create your own exception type that extends `RuntimeException` and declare that to be thrown in the interface documentation. Implementations would then use this for wrapping exceptions and you could catch this exception in client code instead of `RuntimeException`. It sounds like the root exception isn't really important for clients (except for logging purposes) as these situations are usually not recoverable.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I will do just that and rethink the documentation of my design to adress the point davidxxx makes in the last part of his answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i am struggling with is how to document the interface, since it
>   will be the first thing a user of my library looks at, when he gets an
>   error (I use the interface throughout my public API instead of the
>   concrete classes). Documenting all the exceptions of the derived
>   classes doesn't sound very appealing to me, since they have no
>   relation at all.

If you want to document these exceptions, I think you consider them as exception to handle for clients. If it is the case, why not using checked exceptions ? 
I know there is two ways of thinking about that but it is interesting in asking ourselves the question.

If you consider that these exceptions are not primordial to be checked and  handled (or thrown), I also don't think you need to reference them in the interface. Besides, theoretically, interfaces should not be coupled to implementations in their specification.
 
 However, you can specify in the interface methods what according to implementations, it may throw `RuntimeException` subclasses. 

Besides, if you master the code source of these exceptions, maybe you could use an abstract class for ancestor exception(s) and make inheriting your subclasses to this abstract class. In this way, you could document this super exception in your interface.

Finally, your design encourage your clients to not program by interface when using DataReceiver subclasses because otherwise clients take the risk not to have specific javadoc and they will not directly see the specific exceptions that may throw methods of the implementation which use .
So, maybe you should also precise it in the interface.

Comment: I could write a whole book about my thought process on checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java, but basically it boils down to: I dislike a lot of forced try-catching and cluttering my subclasses with throws declarations.

Comment: The last part of your answer is very true, do you think i should return the concrete class of my DataReceiver and simply hope. that the client uses the interface in his code to decouple his program from the concrete DataReceiver?

Comment: "it boils down to: I dislike a lot of forced try-catching and cluttering my subclasses with throws declarations." I agree with.

Comment: If concrete classes have too much specificities, I prefer declare them as declared type rather than the interface; When I use a `TreeMap`, I prefer declare `TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap()` than  `Map map = new TreeMap()` because I want to stay aware of specificity of TreeMap.